# remove all npm links

Tags: symbolic-link, npm

I've linked  few projects together and I'm getting some unpredictable behavior, so I want to remove all links and "start fresh"

I've googled this for a while and can't seem to find something that works
it's surprising to me that something like that isn't documented anywhere.

is there's something I'm missing?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Jos added info

Comment: As I understand npm links, they are just symbolic links in the file system. You can find them with `find /path/to/dir/ -type l` and delete them all in one go with `find /path/to/dir/ -type l -delete`.

Comment: @Jos I want to remove all symlinks that were added by npm. This command u mentioned prints out all links in the system